# How to get the current column name in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

What is the function to get the current line number and the current column name for a cell in Excel?

Comment: I just found out the functions `LIN` and `COL` but the problem is they return numbers, and I need the column letter to `INDIRECT` it.

Comment: you can use the `OFFSET` function in conjunction with, or instead of, the `INDIRECT` formula in that case.  If you want to use strings, though, I also updated my answer.

Comment: By the way, INDIRECT is a volatile function, so use it sparingly. It does sound like am OFFSET might be a better choice here if you are basing the reference you want on some calculation of position.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `ROW` and `COLUMN` functions to do this.  If you omit the argument for those formulas, the current cell is used.  These can be directly used with [the `OFFSET` function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324991), or any other function where you can specify both the row and column as numerical values.

For example, if you enter `=ROW()` in cell D8, the value returned is 8.  If you enter `=COLUMN()` in the same cell, the value returned is 4.

If you want the column letter, you can use the `CHAR` function.  I do not recommend the use of letters to represent the column, as things get tricky when passing into double-letter column names (where just using numbers is more logical anyways).

Regardless, if you should still want to get the column letter, you can simply add 64 to the column number (64 being one character less then `A`), so in the previous example, if you set the cell's value to `=CHAR(COLUMN()+64)`, the value returned would be `D`.  If you wanted a cell's value to be the cell location itself, the complete formula would be `=CHAR(COLUMN()+64) & ROW()`.

---

Just an FYI, I got 64 from an ASCII table.  You could also use the `CODE` formula, so the updated formula using this would be `=CHAR(COLUMN() + CODE("A") - 1)`.  You have to subtract 1 since the minimum value of `COLUMN` is always 1, and then the minimum return value of the entire formula would be `B`.

However, this will not work with two-letter columns.  In that case, you need the following formula to properly parse two-letter columns:

```
=IF(COLUMN()>26,IF(RIGHT(CHAR(IF(MOD(COLUMN()-1,26)=0,1,MOD(COLUMN()-1,26))+64),1)="Y",CHAR(INT((COLUMN()-1)/26)+64) & "Z",CHAR(INT((COLUMN()-1)/26)+64) & CHAR(IF(MOD(COLUMN(),26)=0,1,MOD(COLUMN(),26))+64)),CHAR(COLUMN()+64))&ROW()
```

I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do it or not, but I know that works from cell `A1` to `ZZ99` with no problems.  However, this illustrates why it's best to avoid the use of letter-based column identifiers, and stick with pure number-based formulas (e.g. using the column number instead of letter with `OFFSET`).

Comment: It will work only for the first 26 columns. But that will do.

Comment: @Jader Dias that is why I recommend that you use `OFFSET` instead, which allows you to specify columns as numbers.  Regardless, I updated the answer with a formula to extend it to work with two-letter columns.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got so many votes when Scot's answer is SO much better, except that he did not explain it. No complex formula needed. I added a comment to explain why/how it works.

Comment: This works until you move to AA etc then its not going to work.

Comment: @krystanhonour use the last formula from my answer in that case... `However, this will not work with two-letter columns. In that case, you need the following formula to properly parse two-letter columns:`

Comment: In the end I used Scot Suttons solution

Comment: This combined with Scott's answer is the solution for me

Answer (score 50):

Try the following function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")
```

Explanation: `ADDRESS(row_num, column_num, [abs_num])`. `[abs_num] = 4` = relative address. That means there are no '$'s in the returned value. For Column 'AB', the `ADDRESS` will return 'AB1'. The substitute remove the '1'.

Comment: This is the most concise and reliable. It's even shorter than VBA counterparts when written in the form `[SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")]`

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address"),"$" & ROW(),""), "$", "")
```

This gives you exact column header, without any $ etc.

Answer (score 3):

Type this into any cell:

**Español**:

```
=SI(ENTERO((COLUMNA()-1)/26)=0;"";CAR((ENTERO(COLUMNA()-1)/26)+64))&CAR(COLUMNA()-(ENTERO((COLUMNA()-1)/26)*26)+64)
```

**English**:

```
=IF(INT((COLUMN()-1)/26)=0,"",CHAR((INT(COLUMN()-1)/26)+64))&CHAR(COLUMN()-(INT((COLUMN()-1)/26)*26)+64)
```

You can replace column() by row number.

Answer (score 2):

To get column name I used the following formulae.

For a particular cell:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",H3),"$" & ROW(H3),"")
```

For the current cell:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address"),"$" & ROW(),"")
```

---

Try this variation. It works on 3-letter columns, and doesn't leave a "$" on the front end:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(XFD123),COLUMN(XFD123),4),ROW(XFD123),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly manual but less VBA and a simpler formula:

- In a row of Excel, e.g. cell A1, enter the column number `=column()`
- In the row below, enter `=Address(1,A1)`
- This will provide the result `$A$1`

Once values are copied, find and replace `$` and `1` with blank.

Answer (score 2):

This will work as well

```
=MID(CELL("address"),2,FIND("$",CELL("address"),2)-2)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way would be to use something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("MySheet1!"&LOOKUP(COLUMN(),colid)&ROW())
```

Where `colid` refers to a *named* range you would create elsewhere within the workbook comprising two adjacent columns with multiple rows: the first column containing the numbers 1 to n corresponding to the `COLUMN()` number, the second containing the letters A - ZZ, or however many column references you wish to accommodate.  The `ROW()` is fine left as it is to return the Row number.

So if you were to copy the above string to cell A1 of 'MySheet2', it would evaluate as `=MySheet1!A1`, and return the value it found in the corresponding cell of `MySheet1`.

This would enable you, for example, to use `MySheet1` as a working area, to delete and re-insert new data, whilst any formatting or calculations in `MySheet2` that refer to those contents will continue to work correctly with the new datasets from the target tabbed worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for polish Excel version:

- for a particular cell:

```
=PODSTAW(PODSTAW(KOMÓRKA("adres";B1);"$" & WIERSZ();""); "$"; "")
```

- for the current cell:

```
=PODSTAW(PODSTAW(KOMÓRKA("adres");"$" & WIERSZ();""); "$"; "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA, user defined formula, solution.  It works with 1, 2, & 3 letter columns.

Put the following in a code module:

```
Function COLUMNLETTER(Optional rng As Range) As String
    'Returns the Column Letter of the top left cell in rng.

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.Caller
    COLUMNLETTER = Left(rng.Address(0, 0), IIf(rng.Column > 26, IIf(rng.Column > 702, 3, 2), 1))

End Function
```

=COLUMNLETTER() in any cell will return the column letter of the cell.
=COLUMNLETTER(B3) in any cell will return **B**.

This User Defined Function works great when creating generic formulas inside the INDIRECT function.

Answer (score 0):

```
=MID(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2,FIND("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2)-2)
```

The address formula works by returning the column and row name. The returned format will always be `$(Column Letters)$(Row Numbers)` - e.g. `$AA$2` or `$XAA$243556`

If we know that $ will always occur at the first character, we can use the first mid formula to start pulling characters after the first $ sign (i.e. the 2nd character).

Then, we find the next $ sign (as we know there will only be two) and we know how many characters there are between the first and the second dollar sign. The rest is simple subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can find the column heading (i.e. the letter):

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()),LEN(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()))-2),LEN(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()))-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),LEN(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following formula works no matter where you put it (it will give you back the column name).

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"$",""),ROW(),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the current cell's column is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4),ROW(),"")
```

The `ROW([reference])` function returns the row's cardinal number of the referenced cell. `ROW()` returns the cardinal number of the row of the current cell.

The `COLUMN([reference])` function returns the column's cardinal number of the referenced cell. `COLUMN()` returns the cardinal number of the column of the current cell.

The `ADDRESS(row_num, column_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet_text])` returns the address (column+row) of the given input. If `[abs_num]` is `4`, then the function returns a fully relative address (no `$`). `[a1]` and `[sheet_text]` are optional parameters and the default behavior is correct.

So, `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4)` is the relative address of the current cell.

Now we just need to remove the row number. Well, we already have a function that returns the row number: `ROW()`. And the column name will not interfere with that because it's always letters. So we can use simple string substitution to remove the row number and replace it with an empty value:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4),ROW(),"")
```

You can replace `ROW()` with a static value like `1` in the function, but in my experience I often want to get the current address in the same spreadsheet where I want the column name, so I find this one more flexible.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

> =IF(COLUMN()>26,CHAR(COLUMN()/26 +64),"") & CHAR(MOD(COLUMN()-1,26)+65) & ROW()

this function effective until "ZY1" or column=701

Comment: Please expand this answer by explaining what these functions are.

Comment: get the current column name in Excel, such as "A1", "B1", ...
even up such as  "AA1", "BA1", "CA1", ...

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(COLUMN()>702,RIGHT(LEFT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),4),3),IF(COLUMN()>26,RIGHT(LEFT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),3),2),RIGHT(LEFT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2),1)))
```