# HLOOKUP Return Greatest Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I have some columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G with some values in the rows below 2, 3, 4. I don't know if HLOOKUP is the correct answer for what I am trying to do but I want to have a function that looks at the values in row 4, finds the highest/greatest value, and then return the column name/label.

I am really rusty with Excel (this is 2011 by the way) so excuse me if it is a noob question. Don't waste your time telling me how easy it was to do. Just show me the solution.

Comment: This thread may help:  http://superuser.com/questions/316239/how-to-get-the-current-column-name-in-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
=INDIRECT("R1C" & MATCH(MAX(4:4),4:4,0),FALSE)
```

Here's another:

```
=INDEX(1:1,0,MATCH(MAX(4:4),4:4,0))
```

By the way, I was assuming by column name/label that you meant the header row value...

Comment: I found that it actually needed to be
    =INDIRECT("R1C" & MATCH(MAX(4:4),4:4,0),FALSE)

Comment: I prefer the INDEX method....but that also requires 0 as 3rd argument of MATCH, i.e. `=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(MAX(4:4),4:4,0))`

Comment: @all Thanks for reminding me that there's a 3rd parameter in Match. When I tested it, it seemed to work with just 2 so it simply slipped my mind. I added the 0s to assist future viewers.