# Formula to return just the Column Letter in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a formula I can use in any cell that will return the column LETTER of the column the formula is in,

I can get the LETTER and ROW number using the below, but I cant get it without the ROW information

```
=ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col"))
```

I don't mind using vba to work it out if there isn't a formula that can achieve this.

NOT A DUPLICATE OF [How to get the current column name in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/316239/how-to-get-the-current-column-name-in-excel)
I only want the COLUMN and not the line number !

Comment: I want JUST the column letter, he wanted current line number and the current column name, so no its not a duplicate, please actually read both questions before making assumptions

Comment: There are answers to that questions which actually gives what you need. If you think it's not relevant for your question, then please explain why solutions offered there aren't work for you.

Comment: if it was dupe of that question, he would have already solved it with his original formula

Comment: so if there ARE answers to my question, why have you copied in a link that DOESNT answer my question ?

Comment: It is absolutely a duplicate of the above question. There are exact answers in that thread to your question.

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")` - the most concise and reliable

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/511989/74576 was really helpful in explaining how to get the column letter in Excel (also works in Google Sheets).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FYI on your original formula you don't actually need to call the **CELL** formula to get row and column you can use:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```

Then as an extension of that you can use **MID** & **SEARCH** to find the **$** and trim down the output so you are just left with the letter:

```
=MID(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))+1,SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))+1)-2)
```

**edit**
You can even simplify this further:

```
=MID(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2,SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2)-2)
```

As per comment from @engineertoast below

Comment: brilliant ! I did try using substitute but then couldn't remove the numbers, THANKS

Comment: Why not just only use Row() or Column()?

Comment: =COLUMN() only gives the column number, not the letter

Comment: @EngineerToast hey i just tried your formula, and something strange is happening, i drag it across multiple columns and they all return the same value, try it out let me know what happens for you please

Comment: i think using CELL("address") makes it volatile

Comment: @User91504 You're exactly right. Using `CELL` makes it reference the active cell as of the last calculation which is supremely unhelpful in this application... Simplifying the `MID` function is still valid, though. To avoid confusion, I'll delete / repost that comment without the `CELL` suggestion.

Comment: Since the first $ will always be the first character, you can simplify that MID function, right? =MID(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2,SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLU‌​MN()),2)-2)

Comment: updated my answer to reflect your simplified version @EngineerToast